# How telescoping sum is applied in this case?

Tags: summation, machine-learning

I am reading the book Foundation of Machine Learning, and the author has many proofs for different theorems. Here is one part of a proof about Perceptron algorithm which I don't quite understand

Note: $w_t$ is a vector

Let 
\begin{equation}
w_{t+1} = \begin{cases}
w_t + ny_t x_t & \text{if } y_t(w.x_t) < 0 \\
w_t & \text{if } y_t(w.x_t) > 0 \\
w_t & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

and in the proof, he has
\begin{equation}
\|w_{T+1}\| = \sqrt{\sum_{t \in T} \|w_{t+1}\|^2 - \| w_t \|^2}
\end{equation}

he mentioned that above equation uses (telescoping sum, $w_0 = 0$). I have no idea why lhs is equal to rhs using telescoping sum, can you help me explain this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an algebraic identity that has very little to do with the specific function: for *any* $f\colon \mathbb Z_{\ge0} \to \mathbb R_{\ge0}$ be any function satisfying $f(0)=0$, we have
$$
f(T+1) = \sqrt{\sum_{0\le t\le T} \big( f(t+1)^2-f(t)^2 \big)}.
$$
To see this, it's equivalent to show that
$$
f(T+1)^2 = \sum_{0\le t\le T} \big( f(t+1)^2-f(t)^2 \big).
$$
And this is easy to show by induction, or indeed by recognizing that the right-hand side is a telescoping sum. Taking $T=3$ for example:
$$
f(4)^2 = (f(1)^2-f(0)^2) + (f(2)^2-f(1)^2) + (f(3)^2-f(2)^2) + (f(4)^2-f(3)^2).
$$

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of perceptron, in the training scenario, for every input, you change the weights in such a way to minimize the error (typically mean squared error). The delta weight vector is perpendicular to the current weight vector.

Hence $\|w_{t+1} \|^2 = \|w_{t} \|^2 + \|ny_tx_t \|^2 (\text{ if  } y_t(wx_t)<0)$.

Writing it in the following way helps you see this more clearly:

\begin{align}
\|w_{T+1} \|^2 &= \|w_{T} \|^2 + \|ny_Tx_T \|^2 (\text{ if  } y_T(wx_T)<0) \\
&= \|w_{T-1} \|^2 + \|ny_{T-1}x_{T-1} \|^2 (\text{ if  } y_{T-1}(wx_{T-1})<0) + \|ny_Tx_T \|^2 (\text{ if  } y_T(wx_T)<0) \\
&\ldots
\end{align}

Since $w_0$ is zero. This simplifies to the desired expression .